# Reading unknown amount of bytes from IdTCPServer connection in delphi

Tags: delphi, indy10, delphi-10.2-tokyo

I am setting up a client/server program to send and receive unknown amount of byte in my application. How to receive unknown buffer size in my program?

I pass my data to `TIdBytes` variable and sending it with this line:

```
IdTCPClient.IOHandler.Write(TIdBytes_Var);
```

The first byte of `TIdBytes_Var` determine packet size and varies due to other condition. I take care of the size of the package to not exceed 1024 byte.

On the receiver side (IdTCPServerExecute) I add this line to read all bytes:

```
var
  byte_buffer: TIdBytes;
begin
  AContext.Connection.IOHandler.ReadBytes(byte_buffer,-1,false); 
end;
```

On debugging mode, after I send first packet from client to the server, an exception is raised:

> raised exception class EConvertError with message ''' is not a valid floating point value

And on running mode only loss my connection.

Where is the problem, and how can I receive all bytes from Indy's input buffer?

Here is my minimal code:

In the client making packet and finally set event that is passed to other thread

```
//create packet. Buffer_to_send is a TIdBytes variable on unit of network thread (U_network_thread).
SetLength(U_network_thread.Buffer_to_send,(6 + (tmp_ints * 12)));//set buffer lenght dynamically, tmp_ints is my record counter(shortint)
tmp_int:= 2;//tmp_int is the integer variable
U_network_thread.Buffer_to_send[0]:= $1;//header sign
U_network_thread.Buffer_to_send[1]:= tmp_ints;//tmp_ints is my record counter as short integer
while tmp_ints > 0 do
begin
  Read(My_File,tmp_rec);//read record from bin file
  Move(tmp_rec,U_network_thread.Buffer_to_send[tmp_int],12);//12 is record lenght
  tmp_int:= tmp_int + 12;   //add pointer
  dec(tmp_ints);
end;
tmp_int2:= zone_i;//integer info
Move(tmp_int2,U_network_thread.Buffer_to_send[tmp_int],4); //add info to the packet
Frq_Evt.SetEvent;   //set event to triger sending on other thread
```

On the net_thread, after connecting to the server and receive ack sign by `ReadLn` command, I wait for event

```
procedure TNetThread.Execute;
  .//create IdTCPClient1 and connect to server
  .//receive ack from server by IdTCPClient1.IOHandler.ReadLn command
  .//wait for event
  while(true) do
    if (FEvent.WaitFor(200) = wrSignaled) then//Buffer_to_send fill on main thread
    begin
      //send buff
      if sending_buf(Buffer_to_send) then
      begin
        //sending ok
      end
      else
      begin
        //sending error
      end;
    end;
  end;
end;
    
function TNetThread.sending_buf(T_Buffer: TIdBytes): boolean;
begin
  try
    IdTCPClient1.IOHandler.Write(T_Buffer)
    result := true;
  except
    result := false;
  end;
end;
```

On the server side, after connecting, sending ack sign by `WriteLn` command, and on the `IdTCPServerExecute` I try to do

```
procedure Tmain_form.IdTCPServerExecute(AContext: TIdContext);
var
  byte_buffer: TIdBytes;
begin
  AContext.Connection.IOHandler.ReadBytes(byte_buffer,-1,false);
  //do something else
end;
```

All work fine and connection passed and server send ack sign to client. Client receive it and wait for event. After event occurs, client making up packet and pass it to net_thread. Packet is good and sending is too. But on the server side raise the problem.

Answer (score 1):

> the first byte of TIdBytes_Var determine packet size and varies due to other condition.

So, then simply read 1 byte first, then read how many additional bytes it says, eg :

```
AContext.Connection.IOHandler.ReadBytes(byte_buffer, AContext.Connection.IOHandler.ReadByte, false);
```

> I take care of the size of the package to not exceed 1024 byte.

A single byte can not exceed 255, so your max packet size would be 256, including the size byte.

> on debugging mode after i send first packet from client to the server rise a problem and receive:
>   "raised exception class EConvertError with message ''' is not a valid floating point value"

There is no way the code you have shown can raise that exception.

**Update**

> Here is my minimal code

Seeing your code now, I can see that despite your earlier claim, the *first* byte of your packet is NOT a packet size, it is always `$01`. In fact, there is no packet size stored in the packet at all. The *2nd* byte contains the number of 12-byte records stored in the packet, and the packet has 6 fixed bytes, so the max packet size is actually 3066 bytes.

Try something more like this:

passed to other thread

```
// create packet. Buffer_to_send is a TIdBytes variable on unit of network thread (U_network_thread).
SetLength(U_network_thread.Buffer_to_send, (6 + (tmp_ints * 12))); // set buffer length dynamically, tmp_ints is my record counter(shortint)
tmp_int := 2; // tmp_int is the integer variable
U_network_thread.Buffer_to_send[0] := $1; //header sign
U_network_thread.Buffer_to_send[1] := tmp_ints; // tmp_ints is my record counter as short integer
while tmp_ints > 0 do begin
  Read(My_File, tmp_rec); // read record from bin file
  Move(tmp_rec, U_network_thread.Buffer_to_send[tmp_int], 12); // 12 is record length
  Inc(tmp_int, 12); // add pointer
  Dec(tmp_ints);
end;
tmp_int2 := GStack.HostToNetwork(UInt32(zone_i)); // integer info, in network byte order
Move(tmp_int2, U_network_thread.Buffer_to_send[tmp_int], 4); // add info to the packet
Frq_Evt.SetEvent; // set event to trigger sending on other thread
```

```
procedure Tmain_form.IdTCPServerExecute(AContext: TIdContext);
var
  byte_buffer: TIdBytes;
  Header: Byte;
  Count: Word;
  Zone: Integer;
begin
  Header := AContext.Connection.IOHandler.ReadByte; // should always be $01
  Count := AContext.Connection.IOHandler.ReadByte; // record counter
  AContext.Connection.IOHandler.ReadBytes(byte_buffer, Count * 12); // records
  Zone := AContext.Connection.IOHandler.ReadInt32; // zone
  // process as needed...
end;
```

Comment: thanks to Remy Lebeau. A single byte can not exceed 255, so... this byte count my record.

Comment: i'm trying to read first byte but problem rise again. immediately after sending packet from sender in the receiver rise this problem. the IdTCPServerExecute don't execute and only connection is loss and on debug mode get this error. i'm define a byte and trying to read it from buffer by adding only this line: tbyte:= AContext.Connection.IOHandler.ReadByte;.

Comment: Then you are doing something wrong. Please [edit your question](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/54599362/edit) to include a [mcve] showing *exactly* how the client prepares and sends `TIdBytes_Var`, and *exactly* how the server tries to read `byte_buffer`.